# facing issue while draw shape on bing map using angular

Tags: angular, dictionary, bing

i used following code for draw shape on bing map, but it throw an error while getting maplayer and drawing tools,

while run the project debugger not hit and variables becomes empty and that cause an error in my project and not work properly, any solution for that?

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule(['Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools', 'Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath'], function () {
        this.drawingLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
        debugger;
        this.map.layers.insert(this.drawingLayer);
        debugger;
        this.tools = new Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools(this.map);
        debugger;
        this.toolsPolyline = new Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools(this.map);
      });
```

[find attachment here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3uGb.png)